# already selected option on a drop down should be colored

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an add more functionality i have a drop down.Here the problem is,if the user selects one option for example 101 and next time when he selects the second option on the second row for example 202, the previously selected option that is 101 should be colored. So that he can identify which option he has selected previously and which and all are remaining to select.

I have already given an alert message on duplicate selection and it is.Now i want previously selected option to be high lightened.
onchange functions calls checkPallet where the value is passed on to the drop down.

HTML CODE:

```
 <td style="border:1px solid #ccc;"><select name="pal<%=rowcc%>" id="pal<%=rowcc%>"  onchange="checkPallet(this.value,this);pal(this.value,this.id);"   style="margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;height:25px;width:120px;text-align:right;padding-right:10px;" >
```

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
 function checkPallet(value, obj)
    {
        if(value!="select")
            {
            var count=0;
            var table = document.getElementById('dTable');
                var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var t=0;t<rowCount-2;t++)
            {
            if(document.getElementById("pal"+(t+1)).value==obj.value) //probably  have to give color in this line
                count++;
            }

            if(count>1)
            {
                obj.selectedIndex=0;
                alert("Pallet already selected please select a new one!");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can add a styling (preferably background color) to the dom element at the same time when you are incrementing the count as well.

Comment: did you `obj.style.background = #f00` near the `count++`?

Comment: yes i tried with obj.style.background = #f00...all the options are displaying with the color.I just want selected option to be high lightened

Comment: It is hard to understand like this.. are you calling this function when the new row is added? Is the ID of new select (whose option needed to be colored)`"pal"+(t+1)`?

Comment: yes i am calling this function when a new row is added..here 't' is the row count...loop runs till the row count is reached...

Comment: Please post the HTML in the question too. What happens if the user changes the already selected value from any above row?

Comment: @techie_28...  if he selects already selected value,he will get an alert message saying that select a new pallet code....

Comment: If the table has 5 rows and value "abc" is selected on row 2.. after adding 4 more rows if user goes back to row 2 & change the value to say "pqr".. what should happen?

Comment: not that complicated...consider user selects an option called 'A' in the row 1 drop down.Second row when he clicks on the drop down ,option 'A' which is already selected on the row 1 should be colored  in row 2 .So that he understands that 'A' is already selected and he will go for other options on row2 except 'A'. In the above mentioned js code obj.value is the option how to provide color to that,i need the proper syntax